# applying changes with dedicated endpoint after all resources are processed

Tags: terraform

I'm working on terraform-provider-ovh where I need to reload configuration only after all the other resources performed their changes.

I can't issue refresh after every resource makes it's own changes as it creates async job and would result in conflicts, plus reload of configuration is a very long operation. I can't find any way to trigger a "handler", "async operation" or some kind of provider scoped post-processing.

My current idea is to create a dedicated resource for "refresh" which can call api to see if there were any changes made and trigger refresh if there are any waiting changes. The problem is that it also needs to be triggered after all the others are done, and I would really want to avoid requiring user to explicitly define depends_on pointing to all resources that might trigger the refresh.

Any ideas for how to solve this reasonable would be very welcome.

Comment: What's wrong with the [existing OVH provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/ovh/index.html)?

Comment: nothing, that is the one I am adding this refresh to

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to achieve here. I think this might be better asked on the issue tracker to the OVH provider instead as they might be able to better understand exactly what you're trying to achieve and why you need something like this for OVH.

Comment: I think the original question should be clear enough, but let me rephrase. there is a resource *ovh_iploadbalancing_tcp_farm_server* (which in fact I wrote), when parsing of all resources like this is done, the provider needs to call */ipLoadbalancing/{serviceName}/refresh* api endpoint. The caveat being, as described before, that it has to happen only after all changes from farm_server resources has been done (destroys and creates), and there are always multiples of these cause when you manage adding backend servers like this, you often deal with more then one operation at a time